# Can I run both a Quadro and GeForce video card at the same time?

Tags: nvidia-geforce, graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

I'd like to use a Quadro video card for some professional applications that I use, but I also like to play games, which would be better suited on a GeForce.

Can I simply put 1 of each of these cards in the computer and have it work? (I suspect not, so...) If not, how could I do something like this if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

I have tested this configuration numerous times, and assuming they're roughly the same age (and not horrible old) you should have no problems getting them to run under Windows 7, simply install the GeForce and Quadro drivers seperately, it's smart enough to figure it out.  Some of the fancier features might act strangely, though.  I have a machine kicking around the office here with a Quadro FX380 and a GeForce 7600GS working fine like this.

EDIT: I don't know that you'll get the kind of performance that you're looking for, though.  But I can guarantee the cards will at least coexist peacefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this of course.
If you want to work with dual graphic cards (ATI - "Crossfire"  /  NVIDIA - "SLI")
You have to get 2 graphic cards which certified for SLI/Crossfire.
The only problem, is that the Quadro series doesn't support SLI.

You'll have to decide what you want - more game-play power (SLI), or more power for professional applications (Quadro)

For more information:

- http://www.nvidia.com/
- http://www.amd.com/

Comment: I don't need SLI capabilities, just to run the two at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here, but from what I've seen it mainly depends on nvidia drivers. Basically Quadro cards should be used with drivers certified for the particular program you're using. I don't think that you can have two versions of nvidia drivers installed at the same time.

I think you should experiment. If you have a GeForce card available, get Riva Tuner. It can force your GeForce card to be detected as equivalent Quadro. You might be able to test out how a Quadro would behave when playing games this way.